# What do we call a privately software developer in general?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I want to refer to a developer who works only for me. What do we call such a developer in general?

My guess is:

> an individual developer or a personal developer or a private developer

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *private*?

Comment: I think you are looking for the word "Freelancer". (Freelance Developer)

Comment: Thank you, snailboat. I think "private" mean not for the public.

Comment: Thank you, holydragon. I think Freelancer belong company, so what I mean is a developer developing self-product and selling, producing.

Comment: Thank you, Maulik V. I grad that I'm easy to undersyand my question.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a personal software developer

This means the developer works only for you. You have hired him/her for the software development.

Yes, *freelance developer* is also correct because freelancers work for clients and not *necessarily* belong to any company. I was a freelance writer and I used to be someone's personal writer then.

The word *private* does not suit there and on the other hand, *individual* developer talks about individuality still not as good as *personal* in **this context.**